# Updating coordinated dictionaries in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have two dictionaries that are acting as a cache, let's call them `d1` and `d2`, with `d2` being a subset a of `d1`.

When I refresh the dictionaries with new entries of d1, I would like the entries in d2 to be refreshed as well. It can be done the obvious way:

```
foreach(var update in updates) {
    d1[update.id] = update;
    if(d2.Contains(update.id))
        d2[update.id] = update;
}
```

But since I'd like to cache other subsets (d3,d4,d5, etc), this may get unwieldy. So I added a "CopyFrom" method to my object, which allows me to maintain the reference by simply just copying properties to the object being updated.

```
foreach(var update in updates) {
    d1[update.id].CopyFrom(update)
}
```

In this way, any other dictionaries that have a reference to the entry won't lose it when `d1` gets updated.

I'd just like to know if I'm missing anything here? I'm just getting back into C# after a break, and my grasp on the obvious may be shaky :).

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to achieve and where you need multiple dictionaries for.

Comment: Basically, I have a very large dictionary that needs to be rearranged into various "views". Rather than do dynamic LINQ queries (slow) on each request, I'd like to cache these views. If the master dictionaries values get updates, I'd like the subcache values to be updated.

Comment: For your views use a list that only contains the relevant keys (without the values). Do a lookup via `d1[d2[index]]`.

Comment: problem is, that would require a lookup for each item in the view. if I have millions of records, that's a lot of lookups. also, i'd have to dump that into a new List or Dictionary if I wanted to subquery further.

Comment: The lookup is nearly o(1) so that should be no problem? Having millions of duplicate cache elements seems like an argument against your own idea.

Comment: True, your approach would just add one more lookup. The duplicate cache elements would just be references though, so they'll just take up as much space as a memory pointer. I'll have a look at doing it this way though, seems simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Why not have a CacheItem class that contains the payload (the current values in your dictionaries). Then for each key in your dictionaries, store a CacheItem containing what you're currently storing. If you store the same CacheItem object in multiple dictionaries, you only need to modify the payload of a CacheItem, and all the dictionaries containing it are updated.

```
foreach(var update in updates) {
    if (d1.ContainsKey(update.id)) {
        var cacheItem = d1[update.id];
        cacheItem.Payload = update;
    } else {
        d1[update.id] = new CacheItem(update);
    }
}
```

My answer assumes that your design of having multiple dictionaries, some being subsets of the main one is based on your requirements, and is a sound way to address them. It seems a little unusual to me.

Comment: Explanation of unusual requirement in question comment above :). Thanks for the suggestion! I think the net effect is the same as the "CopyFrom" method, but is a bit simpler and cleaner, though the CopyFrom method allows me to implement an ICopyableFrom interface, and to create a dictionary subclass for such objects.

Comment: Based on the additional information you've provided, I would agree with the general flavor of other comments to your question. That is, you should separate the notion of cache from the notion of view. The cache should be the single location where your objects are cached. A view should be a collection or array of references into your cache, not mini-caches themselves.

Comment: That's the intent, though I had wanted to store the references not as a lookup, but as the object reference itself. I'll do some performance tests and see how things go.

Answer (score 1):

Well if the value of the Dictionary is a reference type, and you're only modifying it, you wouldn't need to do anything. If you are creating a new reference or it is a value type, I'd change the subsets to be arrays of the type of id which is the subset you'd like to have. And whenever you need the value, you'd still go to d1 for accessing it.

Comment: If the entry is assigned `d1[1]=o1`, and I then assign `d2[1]=d1[1]`, the reference to the object `o1` is copied, not the reference to the entry. If  I update `d1[1]=o2`, then `d2[1]` is still pointing at `o1`.

Comment: @dcpar I'm saying that if you don't reassign the reference. If instead you only do `d1[1].propName = "Hello World"`, you can observe the same change from d2[1]. What you have seems a little hard to maintain in general. If you want to remove an object, you have to go through all the dictionaries and remove the reference to it, otherwise you have a memory leak. Not sure if that's a concern.

Comment: You're right, adding and removing is a concern with this approach for sure. This could be dealt with by having the parent dictionary produce the subquery collections through a factory, with an add/remove event attached.

Answer (score 0):

As for all types of cache keep in mind that [a cache with a bad policy is another name for a memory leak](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/05/02/588350.aspx).

Further: [Caching Implies Policy](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2004/01/19/60280.aspx).